# Who owns the replicant hookers?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

I assume they primarily offer their services to humans but of course we see an exception when the arrangement Joi effected occurs. The "doxies" (as I think they are referred in the script) seem to have a lot of freedom of movement, but I do not believe replicants who do not have owners (K's owner, for instance, is either his superior or the police department itself) are allowed to live on their own. So is there any indication that, for example, a human has purchased several and makes his living off of them?

Comment: “Who replicant dis be?”

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is replicant pimps

Comment: @Valorum: all kidding aside, that is not a very good guess. I believe replicants must be owned and by humans. These hookers do not exist in secret.

Comment: @releseabe - It's replicant owners all the way down

Answer (score 2):

Self-owned, according to the actress that portrays Mariette.

> Mariette is a Doxie, a Replicant pleasure model designed to satisfy
> sexual urges. Mackenzie Davis plays the seductive yet sweet Replicant
> ordered by Freysa to uncover information about K. **“Mariette is a part
> of an organization of hopeful Replicants,” explains the actor. “They
> know there’s a future for them, that they’re not disposable.”** Denis
> Villeneuve selected Mackenzie Davis early in the casting process. “She
> was the most obvious choice for the role. She’s one of the best
> actresses of her generation, plus she looks like she could be Daryl
> Hannah’s little sister.” Although she plays a Doxie, the character
> created by Mackenzie Davis is playful and a little mischievous. “Being
> on that set was surreal. Once in a while, I’d look around and think,
> ‘Oh damn, this is the coolest thing in the world.’”
>
> <sub><sup>[The Art and Soul of Blade Runner 2049](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_and_Soul_of_Blade_Runner_2049)</sup></sub>

Under the circumstances, since Replicants aren't people, I think we can reasonably assume that their organisation has a nominal human owner somewhere along the chain.